# Catel Mvvm Plugins PropertyGrid

Tags: mvvm, propertygrid, catel

I would like to know. How I can dynamically choose view? I would like to make the PropertyGrid in my application. The PropertyGrid should must change when user selects object. As I understand for this task I have to use a DataTemplate but how I can dynamically create DataTemplate in code? The fact is that I use plug-ins and View and ViewModel for each plugin located in separate dll and so I can't directly write DataTemplate in PropertyesViewModel.
How can I make the edit properties for each plugin using the Propertygrid if I can't use a DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

For Catel it doesn't matter in which assemblies the views / view models are located since it uses relative naming conventions. However, if you want to show a custom view based on logic that might reside inside a plugin, I think this is out of scope for Catel.

To solve this issue, you must implement a custom service that can communicate with the plugins and resolve the right view for a selected object. One solution might be naming conventions (if it's a PersonModel, you might want to show the PersonPropertiesView and PersonPropertiesViewModel). However, this must be a custom service.